# While loop and getchar function assistance

Tags: c

I'm new to C programming and I'm facing some problem doing this question that requires me to use a while loop, and a nested switch function. If the input by user is -1 at the start of loop, the switch terminates.

I am supposed to use the getchar() function to determine if the while loop continues.

I have tried to replace the EOF with -1, but later found out that getchar() only reads one character. '-1' is two characters. It also reads a character, and if it's an integer, will always return as an unsigned integer.

The contents are alright, I'm just **having trouble in the while loop, and the getchar function :**

```
 while (paycode = getchar()) != EOF)
```

Where the input that will cause the while loop to end  is supposed to be **-1**. I also face a problem, that for some reason, the prinf("Enter pacode") **repeats twice**. I know that the code can look a tad messy and unoptimized, pardon me!

Any advice, optimization, suggestions and feedback will be greatly appreciated. Attached is a sample of my code.

```
int main(void)

{
    int paycode, managersalary, grossweeklysales, overtime;
    float hourlysalary,comissionsalary ,piecepay, piecenumber, piecewage;

    unsigned int totalhours, managercount = 0, hourlycount = 0, comissioncount = 0 , piececount = 0;

    printf("Enter paycode (-1 to end): ");

    while ( (paycode = getchar()) != EOF) { //How to replace by EOF with -1? Do I use default: then?
        //what If I use switch loop only or with a for loop?


        switch (paycode) {

        case '1':
            printf("Manager selected.\n");
            printf("Enter weekly salary: ");
            scanf("%d", &managersalary);
            printf("Manager's pay is $%d", managersalary);

            managercount++;
                break;

        case '2':
            printf("Hourly worker selected.\n");
            printf("Enter hourly salary: ");
            scanf("%f", &hourlysalary);
            printf("Enter total hours worked: ");
            scanf("%d", &totalhours);
                    
            if (totalhours > 40) {
                overtime = totalhours - 40;
                printf("Worker worked %d overtime hours\n", overtime);
            }
                
                printf("Worker's pay is $%.2f.", (hourlysalary*40)+(1.5*hourlysalary)*overtime);
                    break;  

        case'3':
            printf("Comission worker selected.\n");
            printf("Enter gross weekly sales: ");
            scanf("%d", &grossweeklysales);
            comissionsalary = 250 + grossweeklysales*(5.7 / 100);
            printf("Comission worker's pay is $%.2f", comissionsalary);

            comissioncount++;
                break;

        case '4':
            puts("Pieceworker selected.");
            printf("Enter number of pieces: ");
            scanf("%f", &piecenumber);
            printf("Enter number of pieces: ");
            scanf("%f", &piecewage);
            piecepay = piecenumber * piecewage;

            printf("Pieceworker's pay is $%.2f", piecepay);

            piececount++;
            break;
            
        }
        printf("Enter paycode (-1 to end): ");
```

Comment: If you're asking how to create an end-of-file condition on console input, that depends on the OS. On Unix-like OSs, you type Ctrl-D. On Windows I think it's Ctrl-Z. Your bigger problem will probably be mixing getchar() and scanf().

Comment: `EOF` does not have to be `-1`, it can by any negative number.

Comment: `getchar()` returns a number. If it successfully reads a character, it returns that character. (Characters are just small numbers). If it is unable to read a character, it returns `EOF` (which may or may not be equal to `-1`). `EOF` is a number which is not equal to any character. `-1` is also a number, not "two characters", in the exact same way `EOF` is not "three characters".